# Outlook permission on folder vba

Tags: vba, permissions, outlook, directory

First, I want to apologize for my poor English and possibly, the question. I searched a whole day for a possibility to add permissions to a outlook folder via a vba-script, but without results.

We want to create a folder in the inbox and give a specific system user the right to read and write to this folder. This is necessary, because a web-based intranet application has to write into this personal folder in outlook.

All new users of our application must create this folder in outlook and give read/write permission to the system user. For some users its very difficult to manage it and therefore I want to develop an addin in outlook making all this steps automatically.

I read something about Redemption and ACE, but I was unable to use those two libraries, because they are not installed on the system or I don't know how to include them into my Outlook script.

I thought I could write a batch-file that will set up all necessary permissions. Is this possible ? Is there somebody else who have experience with this subject?

I'm looking forward to your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi to work with the folder's PR_ACL table or you can use Redemption (which exposes this functionality to any language).

Why exactly you couldn't use Redemption? All you need to install it is to register it using regsvr32.exe.

Comment: thank you for your response. i cant find the redemption.dll, i think this is the problem? I think i must execute  "regsvr32.exe redemption.dll"